# Need Help to Include infinite-scroll in fancy-select on angularjs + ionic

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm using this directive in my application http://jsfiddle.net/q62jx3s6/ This is angularjs with ionic , my problem is when i try to use the infinite-scroll in this directive to load more data only when i scroll:

First i will go show my code and after the problem.

**fancy-select-items.html i put here:**

```
        <label class="item item-input">
            <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
            <input type="search" ng-model="search" placeholder="Buscar ...">
        </label>
        <!-- Multi select -->
        <ion-toggle
                    ng-repeat="item in items | filter:search"
                    ng-if="multiSelect"
                    ng-checked="item.checked"
                    ng-model="item.checked"
                    class="item item-text-wrap">
            {{item.text}}
        </ion-toggle>

        <!-- Single select -->
        <ion-item
               ng-repeat="item in items | filter:search"
               ng-if="!multiSelect"
               class="item item-text-wrap"
               ng-click='validateSingle(item)'>
            {{item.text}}
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
    
    <ion-infinite-scroll spinner on-infinite="loadMore()" distance="10%">

    </ion-infinite-scroll>
</ion-content>
```

and in the directive of fancy-select i put this:

```
  scope.loadMore = function() {
      $timeout(function() {
          scope.items.push({
              id: "1",
              text: "teste"
          });
          console.log('inseriu');
          $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollReady');
          $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
          $scope.$broadcast('scroll.resize');

      }, 500);
  }
```

**and in my form template i put this:**

```
    <fancy-select
                  header-text="Parcero"
                  allow-empty='false'
                  value="formData.parcero"
                  text="elparcero"
                  items="parceros"   
                  ng-change="change()"
                  ng-model="formData.parcero">
    </fancy-select>
```

**controller:**

```
$scope.parceros = [];

var query = "SELECT * FROM cadc001 WHERE cd_empresa =" + sessao.getData("sess_empresa") + " LIMIT 1, 30";
$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, []).then(function(res) {
       if (res.rows.length > 0) {
           for (var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {
               $scope.parceros.push({
                   id: res.rows.item(i).id,
                   text: unescape(res.rows.item(i).nome),
                   checked: false,
                   icon: null
               });
           }
       }
}, function(err) {
       console.error(err);
});

$scope.elparcero = 'Selecione un Parcero';
```

When i try open the application and i click on the select  he open the modal, then i scroll to the bottom he start to add many items and not stop, stay adding in loop. Is wrong he have to add only 1 item when i scroll , 1 item per time.

**in my log:**

```
   ....
6     655085   log      inseriu
7     655621   log      inseriu
8     656220   log      inseriu
9     656826   log      inseriu
10    657357   log      inseriu
11    657897   log      inseriu
12    658433   log      inseriu
13    658965   log      inseriu
14    659505   log      inseriu
15    660041   log      inseriu
16    660577   log      inseriu
17    680685   log      inseriu
18    680697   log      inseriu
......
```

**Have to work like this, one per time when scroll to the bottom:**

http://codepen.io/elm/pen/Becqp

Please Help me, My English is not so good sorry me by the wrong words.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/q62jx3s6/ -> fancy-select

Answer (score 0):

try moving the code inside `$apply`

```
    $timeout(function() {

     $scope.$apply(function(){   
       scope.items.push({
         id: "1",
         text: "teste"
       });
       console.log('inseriu');
       $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollReady');
       $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
       $scope.$broadcast('scroll.resize');
    });

   }, 500);
```